# Under what circumstances are Red Hat kernels provided to CentOS?

Tags: centos, rhel, opensource-projects

I'm a little confused on how/when Red Hat kernels are provided to the CentOS development team for inclusion.  Is that solely at Red Hat's discretion? Are kernels built under RH extended lifecycle support arrangements freely available? That wouldn't make sense from a business perspective for RH so I'm guessing that there isn't a open-source license restriction requiring them to publish ALLLLLL kernels for free.

Comment: Yes, there is a GPL restriction on the Linux kernel requiring anyone who modifies it to make those changes available for free.

Comment: Anyone who *distributes* it, and you can charge for it.

Comment: RH follows the letter of the GPL but subverts the spirit, making it inconvenient for others to use/cherry-pick from their patches.  Up until 2011 they provided separate patches for each change.  Since then, they don't.  They do provide separate patches to customers with support contracts (but with a clause allowing them to cancel the support contract if the customer distributes them - technically probably legal because RH has no obligation to keep a customer they don't want).    See https://lwn.net/Articles/432012/ for details.

Comment: Note: this was the case last time i looked in to (a few years ago) but may have changed since.  And it's important to remember that RH **do submit their patches upstream to the linux kernel devs**.  In fact, they are one of the major contributors to the kernel.